# How to call javascript by passing multiple arguments from c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Can anyone please tell me how to pass arguments to javascript from c#?

I used `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, but it is not calling the method.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();da = o1.viewThisAddMoreFields(Convert.ToInt32(id));

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   da.Fill(dt);

   int count = dt.Rows.Count;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

   {

     extraFieldName[i] = dt.Rows[i]["FieldName"].ToString();

     extraFieldValue[i] = dt.Rows[i]["FieldValue"].ToString();
   }


  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

  {



                 ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();

                 ModalPopupExtender2.Hide();

                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ExtraFName", "extraFieldName[i]");

                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ExtraFValue", "extraFieldValue[i]");

                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("totalCount", "count");


                 // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: moreFieldsEditFunction(); ", true);"+extraFieldName[i].ToString()+","+extraFieldValue[i].ToString()+"




             }

             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

             {
                // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"Javascript", "javascript: moreFieldsEditFunction('Hai','Hello');", true);

                 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "xx", "<script>moreFieldsEditFunction(" + extraFieldName[i] + "," + extraFieldValue[i] + ");</script>");
             }
```

Javascript code is:

```
 function moreFieldsEditFunction(extrafname,extrafvalue) {


         alert(extrafname + "test" + extrafvalue + "Helloooooo");

     }
```

Is this format correct?

I can able to call using single parameter, but when passing two parameters it is not working. Any syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name in single quotes as string variables need to be passed in quotes.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "xx", "<script>moreFieldsEditFunction('" + extraFieldName[i] + "','" + extraFieldValue[i] + "');</script>");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I made a mistake in calling javascript.After adding single quotes it works well.Thank you.